# Rspec test fails with method missing, but not from RubyMine Spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I've got a very simple RSpec/Rails3 test that fails when run like this:

```
bundle exec ruby -I spec /home/user/project/my_test_spec.rb
```

but the test passes just fine when run within RubyMine using the spork server, but fails when run without spork.

The failure is:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Where "name" is a db column name, and the object is an ActiveRecord retrieved by calling

```
subject { MyTable.find_by_table_id 123 }
```

and the test looks like

```
 it "blah blah" do
    subject.name.should == "Correct Name"
 end
```

There must be a simple solution for this. The spec_helper is required at the top of the test and it does call:

```
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
```

Any more info needed?

Comment: The problem I had was that the setup of the test called "save" rather than "save!" and the errors were swallowed. These errors occurred because the test database lacked some lookup table values. What is not clear is why Spork used the development database rather than the test database. It is also not clear why there seems to be no logging of the validation errors when "save" is called.